# Show specific error message - NativeBase/React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native, native-base

Learning react-native at the moment, building a sign up form (using NativeBase components) and want to add validation to each input field.

The issue I am facing at present is that I am not seeing the specific error message come through, always falls back to the default

```
#SignUp.js
export const SignUp = ({navigation}) => {
  const [errors, setErrors] = useState({});

  const validateFirstName = () => {
    if (formData.firstName === undefined) {
    setErrors({
      ...errors,
      name: 'First Name is required',
    });
    return false;
    } else if (formData.firstName.length < 3) {
      setErrors({
        ...errors,
        name: 'First Name is too short',
      });
      return false;
    }
    return true;
  };

  // First Name Input Field
  <FormControl isRequired isInvalid={'name' in errors}>
  <FormControl.Label>First Name</FormControl.Label>
  <Input value={firstName} onChangeText={firstName => setFirstName(firstName)}/>
  {'name' in errors ?
    <FormControl.ErrorMessage>Please enter a valid first name</FormControl.ErrorMessage>: ''
  }
  </FormControl>
}
```

So with this example lets say i submit an empty first name, I would expect to see the error message `First Name is required`, but I get `Please enter a valid first name`

I do not seem to be accessing the error messages correctly, have i missed something ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have missed one small thing. Just replace

```
<FormControl.ErrorMessage>Please enter a valid first name</FormControl.ErrorMessage>: ''
```

To

```
<FormControl.ErrorMessage>{errors.name}</FormControl.ErrorMessage>: ''
```

So, the component `FormControl.ErrorMessage` will display its children when the component is in an `invalid` state. You can read more about it [here](https://docs.nativebase.io/form-control)

**I have created a [snack](https://snack.expo.dev/@md-rehman/formcontrol-example), to show how to effectively use FormControl.**